# Why is an explicit Task variable required to get Tasks to run in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I am trying to use await to make some database data retrieval tasks run in parallel. For some reason it only works if I explicitly create a Task variable and does not work if I directly await the methods that return those Tasks.

I have an example of the problem in a console app below:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This runs sequentially
        await Write("Task 1");
        await Write("Task 2");
        await Write("Task 3");


        //This runs in parallel
        var t1 = Write("Task 1");
        var t2 = Write("Task 2");
        var t3 = Write("Task 3");
        await t1;
        await t2;
        await t3;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task Write(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start - {text}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"End - {text}");
    }
}
```

I expected these two methods to produce exactly the same result.

Comment: Because a `Task` can start when it is created, so before it is awaited. In your first example you create it per await.

Comment: You're running them sequentially. Use `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: `await Write("Task 1");` says 'send one of my kids to the shops and wait until they come back'. `var t1 = Write("Task 1");
        var t2 = Write("Task 2");
        var t3 = Write("Task 3");
        await t1;
        await t2;
        await t3;` says 'send all three kids to the shops and wait until the first one I sent comes back (then wait for the second, then wait for the third)'.

Comment: From the documentation: "The await operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing async method until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand completes" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await).

Comment: I suspect you meant to do `await Task.WhenAll(Write("Task 1"), Write("Task 2"), Write("Task 3"));`

Comment: You need to carefully consider what the keyword `await` means. If you think it *starts* something, that's almost exactly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TAP pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) specifies that tasks are returned "hot", i.e., in-progress. [`await` will pause the current method until its argument completes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

So, this code will call `Write`, which returns an in-progress task. The `await` then pauses the current method until that task completes:

```
await Write("Task 1");
```

Alternatively, this code will call `Write`, which returns an in-progress task. This task is then just placed into a variable. Since there is no `await`, the method is not paused:

```
var t1 = Write("Task 1");
```